# go in four directions from point

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I've got a point at row,col, I'd like to go in four directions with some restrictions. I've tried the following:

```
directions=[(0,1),(1,0),(-1,0),(0,-1)]
isValidIndex=lambda row,col: row<numRows and col<numCols and row>0 and col>0
for row,col in [row+nextRow, col+nextCol for row,col in directions if isValidIndex(row,col)]:
   # Do Some stuff
```

What is the best practice here? I'm getting a syntaxerror so I believe something is incorrect

Comment: Try adding parenthesis like this `for row,col in [(row+nextRow, col+nextCol) for row,col in directions if isValidIndex(row,col)]:`

Comment: @ExplodingGayFish Oh yeah that's the syntax error thnaks

Comment: Also your loop seem really strange since `row,col` are from `directions` (meaning `[(0,1),(1,0),(-1,0),(0,-1)]`) which will not sasisfy `isValidIndex`

Comment: @ExplodingGayFish oh yea that too

Answer (score 0):

You may want something like:

```
[(nextRow + dir[0], nextCol + dir[1]) for dir in directions if isValidIndex(nextRow + dir[0], nextCol + dir[1])]
```